# CloudFormation wants to replace my EKS ControlPlane, but I don't want it to replace

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster that I set up with CloudFormation.  I recently clicked on the button in the EKS UI to upgrade Kubernetes versions.  I think this was a mistake, because now when I run a stack update (adding a new security group resource), CloudFormation is trying to replace my ControlPlane.

I'm curious to know if there is any way I can restore ownership of the stack to CloudFormation in such a way that I could continue deploying stack updates without having to replace this cluster.  It's not such a big deal now with this test cluster, but I wouldn't want to replace a production cluster for this reason.

When I run the `aws cloudformation deploy` from CLI, it creates a change set where I can see that it is marking the ControlPlane as Replace: true.  But it doesn't seem to give any more information than that.  Is there some way to find out *why* it is marking it as replace?  Am I forced to replace it now that I touched the resource outside CloudFormation?

Here's my ControlPlane CF definition:

```
  ControlPlane:
    Type: 'AWS::EKS::Cluster'
    Properties:
      KubernetesNetworkConfig:
        IpFamily: ipv4
        ServiceIpv4Cidr: ''
      Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-eks'
      ResourcesVpcConfig:
        EndpointPrivateAccess: false
        EndpointPublicAccess: true
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref ControlPlaneSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref SubnetPublicUSEAST1A
          - !Ref SubnetPublicUSEAST1D
          - !Ref SubnetPrivateUSEAST1A
          - !Ref SubnetPrivateUSEAST1D
      RoleArn: !GetAtt
        - ServiceRole
        - Arn
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}/ControlPlane'
      Version: '1.25'
```

Edit: Previously the Version in the template was 1.24.  I manually upgraded to 1.25 in the UI.  Then I started getting the replace error on deploy.  So I tried setting the version to 1.25 in the template, but it still wants to replace.

Comment: I think you've misidentified the reason behind the replacement action.  When I look at [the `Version` attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-eks-cluster.html#cfn-eks-cluster-version), I see it requires 'no interruption'.  There are a number of attributes that do require replacement; maybe one of those changed?  Cloudformation holds its own representation of state.  Changing the cluster version externally is not itself enough to make cloudformation  "see" the change.